# Use propositional logic to solve

Tags: first-order-logic, quantifiers

Argue that (∀x(P(x) ∨ ∃y P(y))) is equivalent to ∃x P(x)

Can anyone please explain how to do it?

Comment: You'll need first-order reasoning to show this.  You won't be able to do with propositional logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\forall x\, (P(x) \lor \exists y\,P(y))
\\
\forall x\, (P(x) \lor (\neg P(x) \land \exists y\, P(y))
\\
\forall x\, (\exists y\, P(y))
\\
\exists y\, P(y)
\\
\therefore \exists x\, P(x)
$

Basically $\forall x\, (P(x) \lor \exists y\,P(y))$ reads: for all values $x$ either the proposition holds, or there's some other value ($y$) for which it holds.   Which can be simplified to: there exists some value for which the proposition holds.

Comment: but how can u simply replace y by x?

Comment: @Nandini That's simply renaming. $x$ is just as good as a placeholder as is $y$. You can interchange them as you wish as long as you change _all_ occurences in the context.

Comment: Do note that the title says "Use propositional logic to solve".   This answer (which is correct) uses first-order reasoning as well.

Answer (score 0):

Don't be impressed by the formula.

When you just apply rules, you can observe

1. That x and y have nothing in common, so $\forall x:(P(x) \vee \exists y:P(y))$ rewrites to $(\forall x:P(x)) \vee (\exists y:P(y))$.
2. That x can be substituted for y in $\exists y:P(y)$
3. $\forall x:P(x) \vee \exists x:P(x) \equiv \exists x:P(x)$

(If my memory serves me well)